# iOS Labels only showing '...' instead of expected text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm trying to display the yaw pitch and roll of the device in a label. I cannot seem to get the values to display, it only shows a '...' where the numbers should be. This is my code, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@interface ViewController (){

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) CMMotionManager *motionManager;
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize motionManager;
@synthesize roll;
@synthesize pitch;
@synthesize yaw;

@synthesize xLabel;
@synthesize yLabel;
@synthesize zLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    /** Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIAccelerometer *accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accelerometer.updateInterval = 1.0f/60.0f;
    accelerometer.delegate = self;
     **/
    //motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    //motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0;

    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    NSTimer *timer;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/60.0 target:self selector:@selector(doGyroUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    //CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion = motionManager.deviceMotion;
    //CMAttitude *attitude = deviceMotion.attitude;

    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
}

-(void)doGyroUpdate
{
    double x = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll*180/M_PI;
    double y = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch*180/M_PI;
    double z = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.yaw*180/M_PI;

    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", x];
    xLabel.text = myString;
    myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", y];
    yLabel.text = myString;
    myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", z];
    zLabel.text = myString;
}
```

Comment: Make your labels wider.

Comment: FYI - find a newer tutorial. There is no need for the `@synthesize` lines any more.

Comment: Thank you that worked! Now, how would I make it so the number only displays out to two decimal places?

Comment: You search on how to do that. Don't just ask people to give you solutions please. Do some research before asking questions. You will learn a lot more doing the research and trying things yourself than you will ever learn simply by asking every little detail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`...` indicates the `UILabel` you're using for displaying the text is not as wide as it should be.

Try and make it wider in your storyboard or xib file.

Answer (score -1):

Try -

```
label.numberOfLines = 1;
label.minimumFontSize = 6;
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Or you can try it by storyboard (Autoshrink option) -

[image]

Comment: Why? This will show tiny text in the already tiny label. The proper solution is to make the labels wider, not use a tiny font.

Comment: @rmaddy yes solution is increasing width of label, but if it is not possible above solution can help.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Autolayout for this. Here I have given 2 constraint
1. top from superView
2. leading from superview

Now whatever is your text it will display without .... .
[image]

Comment: How do those two constraints ensure the label is wide enough for the given text? Those two constraints only set the position of the label, not its width.

Comment: It takes as much width as required.it all depends on label content. You can try it will work fine.

Comment: @maddy did this work for u or not.  here i have not given the fixed width constraint as it will restrict to that much width..So whaterever is your content it will display full content...If still it does not work for u..then tell me i will help in that case